# javascript related API to send short text

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an app using javascript for android and I want to send a short text across to users, How can I do that? I Did not get any javascript related API to send short text across two users. "My app is a small game and It needs two players and while playing they have to able to chat." I tried using phonegap but still did not get any api to do so.

Comment: Hey! Please do not forget to mark the answer are accepted if you are satisfied. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a client server architecture. There is not easy way send short texts directly across users.